# Angular 5 - How to maintain an array of ngmodel for the select created from list of array

Tags: angular

I am create a list of columns in which column name is displayed left hand side. Each column contains a list of select box which is given to user.

I have created an example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l8yezg)  where you can see this scenario. 
As select box are creating dynamically how can i maintain a array of ngmodel for each select box.

below is sample code :

```
<select class="form-control p-2 m-2" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" [(ngModel)]="data">
      <option *ngFor="let dropdown of dropdowns" [attr.value]="dropdown">{{dropdown}}</option>

    </select>
```

in above code ngModel name is data and once it is set its value is getting set for all the dropdown present in the page. How can i maintain this ngmodel in my array with column and dropdown selected value mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to bind dynamically to `ngModel` you need to change your structure a bit. like this

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success p-2 m-2">{{col.name}}</button>

<select class="form-control p-2 m-2" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" [(ngModel)]="col.value">
      <option *ngFor="let dropdown of dropdowns"        
          [attr.value]="dropdown">{{dropdown}}</option>
    </select>
    </ng-container>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcdrye?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: Any idea of how can I use the new object to submit in a form?. I have tried with `formControlName="selectedData"` in a Form Builder but I got `Converting circular structure to JSON` error.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid changing your `ngModel`, you can push the data to the array like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
  <select class="form-control p-2 m-2" id="exampleFormControlSelect{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="data[i]">
    <option *ngFor="let dropdown of dropdowns" [attr.value]="dropdown">{{dropdown}}</option>  
  </select>
</ng-container>
```

This way you can get your dynamic data data with the number of the input in ts file `data[i]` without changing your model.